# how to speed up my .bash_history commands

Tags: command-line, bash, command-history

I use my .bash_history all the time using ctrl-R to find complex commands I figured out in the past and since forgot how to run.

I have a large history (50,000) lines, managed by these commands in my .bashrc file.  This was certainly copied from someone on the internet in years past:

```
#for keeping the history from all shells
export HISTIGNORE=lst:df*:top:ssh*:cd*  # don't put these in history
export HISTCONTROL=erasedups    # no duplicate entries
export HISTSIZE=50000           # big big history
shopt -s histappend             # append to history, don't overwrite it
# Save and reload the history after each command finishes
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Now, my problem is that with a huge history, I notice my prompt getting a bit laggy.  If I nuke my .bash_history things get snappy again.  I notice I have a lot of crud in my .bash_history, but manually curating it is not worth the time.

Who has a suggestion to allow me to keep my .bash_history dependance, but to speed up my prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Lose 
`export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"`. 
You don't need to save each command in turn, they are saved automatically at the end of the session.

Comment: yes but if I have a number of shells going it won't add the up to date history to each unless I close them, no?